# CanvasJS synchronize Panning with Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, canvasjs

I am rendering an Graph with CanvasJS.
It´s generated dynamically. 
After I stop the generation (or after an specified time) I generate from that an image.

Now I want to load that image AND take the generation of the Graph. So... I am again generating the same data, but this time with the complete (mostly scaled) picture of the data. - This shall work as an fast Overview.

That´s how I am doing it basiclly: (the dynamic data)

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () 
    {

    var dps = []; // dataPoints
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
      zoomEnabled:true,
        title :{
            text: "Live Random Data"
        },          
        data: [{
            type: "stackedColumn",
            dataPoints: dps            
        }]
    });

    var xVal = 0;
    var yVal = 100; 
    var updateInterval = 100;
    var dataLength = 500; // number of dataPoints visible at any point
      var arr = [];
    var updateChart = function (count) {
        count = count || 1;
        // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.            
        for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {   
            yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
            dps.push({
                x: xVal,
                y: yVal
            });
          arr.push({
                x: xVal,
                y: yVal
            });
            xVal++;
        };
        if (dps.length > dataLength)
        {
            dps.shift();                
        }           
        chart.render();     
    };

    // generates first set of dataPoints
    updateChart(dataLength); 

    // update chart after specified time. 
var d=  setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 

          $("#test").click(function () {
         console.log("baa");
            clearInterval(d);
            });

       $("#show").click(function () {
         console.log("baa");
         dps=[];
          dps.push(arr);
         chart.render();


            });

    }            

</script>
```

http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/dynamic/realtime_line/

Now, if I am zooming or panning the "Live Data" or on the Image:

I want an synchronization between those two. If I am zooming or panning on the Image I only want to see an opaque rect and the dynamic data has to be really zoomed.

An sync. Example is here http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/m5jgk5sg/, but how do I do that with an Image?
Does anyone of you has an idea or how to make an workaround?

Comment: Is my question not understandable or is it too hard to do?